# regex to remove certain pattern matching of data in python

Tags: python, regex

can someone help me with the below scenario?

Input:[14][15] In May 2016, she was one of the 12 candidates nominated by the BJP[16][17] to contest the Rajya Sabha elections due on 11 June 2016.[20]

output:In May 2016, she was one of the 12 candidates nominated by the BJP to contest the Rajya Sabha elections due on 11 June 2016.

i'm working in a project where i am doing web crawling to fetch data from wikipedia.The problem is the data is coming in the above format.I need a regex pattern which filters the data dynamically when it finds the numbers coming inside []. It should not remove other numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

str = '[14][15] In May 2016, she was one of the 12 candidates nominated by the 
BJP[16][17] to contest the Rajya Sabha elections due on 11 June 2016.[20]'

str = re.sub(r'\[\d+]', '', str)

print(str)
```

output

```
'In May 2016, she was one of the 12 candidates nominated by the BJP to contest the Rajya Sabha elections due on 11 June 2016.'
```

You can test your own regular expressions here https://regex101.com/

Comment: can you  explain?i'm not able to understand.

Comment: Try and read this https://ryanstutorials.net/regular-expressions-tutorial/regular-expressions-basics.php

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
import re
str = "[14][15] In May 2016, she was one of the 12 candidates nominated by the BJP[16][17] to contest the Rajya Sabha elections due on 11 June 2016.[20]"
pattern = '\[[^\]]*\]'
line = re.sub(pattern, '', str)
print(line)
```

Result

```
 In May 2016, she was one of the 12 candidates nominated by the BJP to contest the Rajya Sabha elections due on 11 June 2016.
```